# Transfer Value From One Column To Other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I Have Two SQL Table's Columns

1. Column A
2. Column B

Is there any way which only transfer `410015,` From `410015,410016,410017,410018,410019,410020` (which is Column A Value) To Column B using PHP. So the values will look like

- **Column A:** `410016,410017,410018,410019,410020`
- **Column B:** `410015,`

Please Help!!! Thanks.

Comment: use ``explode`` - http://dk1.php.net/explode - (with the delimiter of ``,``) function and extract the first number, add artificially the ``,`` back. Though why you like that "," is not clear

Comment: BTW You can do this modification via SQL as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried **REPLACE** & **CONCAT_WS** and it works.

```
UPDATE Table SET ColumnA = REPLACE(ColumnA , '410015', '') WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%410015%'; 
UPDATE Table SET ColumnB = CONCAT_WS(',', ColumnB, '410015')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can do it via SQL:

```
UPDATE Table
SET ColumnB = SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 1, LOCATE(ColumnA, ','))
WHERE LOCATE(ColumnA, ',') > 0 AND
      ColumnA LIKE '%410015%'
```

Comment: But i want selected value Like, I select '410015' from html form's post method and now I want To transfer from one column to another at one click

Comment: Its great you want something, but if you don't say it in your question no one will know, see my modified query